# how to perform segue and action event for Custom Tab bar Items?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Very new to iOS technology, i am struck with some problem here while using tab bar and items.

Am not been able to connect tab bar items with view thorough reference outlet in my storyboard, how to do that?

How can i implement tab bar at centre as shown in the picture?

Thanks in advance

[image: How can i implement tab bar at centre as shown in the picture?]

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-quick-tip-creating-a-uitabbar-application-with-storyboards--mobile-10449 here is very good tutorial

Comment: Thanks  for the replay but here am using a custom tab bar

Comment: @Naveen https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKTabPageViewController

Comment: Thank you it may help me, may i get that in swift and in simpler way through storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This should just be a control drag option in xcode, you can also view some source which already has these connections made, code here :- https://github.com/deepesh259nitk/MultipleStoryBoards/tree/master

Comment: Thank you but it is not my requirement wait i will post the snapshot of my design part and tell me how to implement that

Comment: Can you paste the xcode story board screen shot in our question as well.

Comment: just i took view controller and tab bar between that added tabbar items but i am not been able to perform segues for other views and how to take tab bar at middle for their respective views?

Comment: they took tab bar controller but i am using only tab bar to customise according to my design if take tab bar controller default it will add at the bottom but i dont want in that way